# How would you run a loop to randomize a community matrix and store them?

Tags: r, matrix, random

I work with community ecology and I am trying to randomize my matrix ~999 times and extract a beta diversity value for each of those 999 times. This will hopefully give me a null distribution to compare my actual values. However, I am having a really hard time running a loop function to do this.

So here's some example data:

```
com.dat<-matrix(c(10,0,0,0,5,0, 0,3,4,0,0,9, 0,0,8,6,0,0, 7,0,9,0,0,0, 
5,3,2,2,1,2),nrow=5,byrow=TRUE)
rownames(com.dat)<-c("Site1","Site2","Site3","Site4","Site5")
colnames(com.dat)<-
c("Species1","Species2","Species3","Species4","Species5","Species6")
```

This is what I would do for one iteration:

```
library(picante)
x<-randomizeMatrix(com.dat, null.model = "richness", iterations = 1000)
library(betapart)
b<-beta.multi.abund(x, index.family = "bray")
```

B is the value I want to keep and have 998 other values of.
So I tried running a loop for just getting 999 matrices that are randomized from the randomizeMatrix function

```
table<-list()

for (i in 1:999) {
  table[i]<-randomizeMatrix(com.dat, null.model = "richness", iterations = 
1000)
}
```

Now my loop making abilities are still at a novice level but I'm pretty sure that above loop should work. Lists are capable of storing multiple matrices (as far as i know) so table[i] should be able to hold 999 randomized version of the initial matrix right? Yet every time I try running it it causes my Rstudio session to timeout.

Ultimately I'd like to get  a dataframe with 999 random values of "b". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do with an `lapply` i..e  `lapply(1:999, function(i) randomizeMatrix(com.dat, null.model = "richness", iterations = 
1000))` to create a `list` of matrices.   Also, if you are using `for` loop, initialize the `list` to the length you require i.e. `lst <- vector('list', 999)` and assign the output like `lst[[i]] <- randomize...`

Comment: @akrun okthank you, i wanted to add that the function code'b<-beta.multi.abund(x, index.family = "bray")'  gives a list of three values. So if every generated matrix puts out a list of 3 values how can I use the apply family to generate a dataframe where each value for each matrix is in it's own columns? For example matrix number one gives me a list of three values in list form and I want each of those values in one column of a new dataframe?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me.  Do you need `do.call(cbind, lapply(1:2, function(i) {x <-  randomizeMatrix(com.dat, null.model = "richness", iterations = 1000);unlist(beta.multi.abund(x, index.family = "bray"))}))` (here I am using only 2 iterations)

Comment: @akrun yes almost! except I want the columns to be bray.bal, bray.gray, and beta.bray (they are rows in your example) and I want the rows to represent every matrix that i do that function to (so that would be 999 rows)

Comment: I posted with the changes you requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using `lapply`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:2, function(i) {
      x <-  randomizeMatrix(com.dat, null.model = "richness", iterations = 1000)
      unlist(beta.multi.abund(x, index.family = "bray"))
    }))
#     beta.BRAY.BAL beta.BRAY.GRA beta.BRAY
#[1,]     0.7686567   0.008321701 0.7769784
#[2,]     0.6693548   0.012815704 0.6821705
```